# What will be the number of combinations in this experiment?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I just wondered what will be the number of combinations in a Experiment.

The experiment as follows -

> Two balls are drawn one by one without replacement from a box containing three balls, numbered $1, 2, 3$. Let $X =$ number on the first ball drawn, $Y =$ number which is larger of the two.

What will be the number of combinations?

First I thought it will be $3$ (i.e., $3C2$), as two balls are chosen out of three.

But I found that the answer is $6$ ($3C1 \cdot 2C1$).

Can anyone please tell me why this is so, and when should I use $3C2$ and when $3C1 \cdot 2C1$?

Comment: "3C2" would be correct , if the order would not matter , that is if "31" is considered to be the same combination as "13"

Comment: The answer depends on how you define your sample space.  If we only care about which balls are selected, we would use combinations.  If we care about the order of selection, then we must use permutations.

Comment: If I upload the question, where I faced the confusion, can you please say me why the order matters here.?

Comment: Typing the exact wording of the question would help.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Two balls are drawn one by one without replacement from a box containing three balls, numbered 1. 2. 3. Let

X= number on the first ball drawn Y= number which is larger of the two.

Comment: Please say me now

Answer (score 1):

Since the random variable $X$ is defined as the number on the first ball drawn, the order of selection matters for that experiment.  Thus, each outcome must be considered an ordered pair.  There are three choices for the first ball and, since the balls are selected without replacement, there are two choices for the second ball.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 2 = 6$ ordered pairs in the sample space.

If we only cared about which balls were selected, we could use combinations.  Since order matters for the random variable $X$, we must use permutations.